# get selected date from DATETIMEPICK_CLASS win32 (NOT mfc)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, datetimepicker

I have 1 **datetimepick_class** control placed on **win32 form**. I create it like below:

```cpp
HWND Date = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    DATETIMEPICK_CLASS,
    TEXT("DateTime"),
    WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,
    10, 10
    250, 30,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)IDC_DATE_TIME_PICK,
    hInst,
    NULL
);
```

And I have **button**. I want when this **button clicked**, it should get **selected date value** from that mentioned **datetimepick** widget.

I handle button clicked event as below:

```cpp
switch (message)
{
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        switch (wmId)
        {
            case IDC_Calculate_Button: 
            //Button clicked so 
            //Display selected date value in msgbox  
        }
}
```

I tried existing answers but they are rare or not well documented or in detailed.
Please guide me.

Comment: Seems like you don't understand the fundamental of Windowing system on Win32. I suggest to read this article first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/windowing

Comment: @UltimaWeapon You are right. I have moved from .net to win32 api so thats why I been struggling. Thanks, I will see and learn these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-getsystemtime) message:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDC_Calculate_Button:
    {
        //Button clicked so 
        //Display selected date value in msgbox  
        SYSTEMTIME st{};
        DateTime_GetSystemtime(Date, &st);
        TCHAR buf[100]{};
        wsprintf(buf, L"%d-%d-%d", st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay);
        MessageBox(hwnd, buf, L"Time", 0);
    }
    }
}
```

It works for me:

[image]